# Uniform distribution over disk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Given two independent random variables $A$ uniform on $[0,1]$ and $B$ uniform on $\left[0,2\pi\right]$. Obtain the joint pdf, transform to the disk, if necessary modify to obtain the uniform pdf over the disk.

The joint pdf factors since $A$ and $B$ are independent. Hence, $f_{A,B}(a,b) = \frac{1}{2\pi}$, right?

Transformation to the disk is done by changing to polar coordinates, i.e. set $X = A \cos B$ and $Y = A \sin B$, then $A = (X^2+Y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $B = \tan^{-1} \frac{Y}{X}$. Changing the coordinates then yields
$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, right?

I do not know about the third part though. Any hints?

Comment: Find an $A\to R$ transformation for polar coordinate $R$ such that $dP/dA=\textrm{const.}$ where $P$ is an area of a disc: $P=\pi R^2$.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/542748/99325

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, $f_{A,B}(a,b)=(2\pi)^{-1}\mathbf 1_{0\lt a\lt1}\mathbf 1_{0\lt b\lt2\pi}$ and $(X,Y)=(A\cos B,A\sin B)$ has density $f_{X,Y}$ where, for every $(x,y)$, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=(2\pi)^{-1}(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}\mathbf 1_{0\lt x^2+y^2\lt1}$.

Starting from some independent $A$ and $B$ with densities $f_A$ on $[0,1]$ and $f_B$ respectively, where $f_B$ is still defined by $f_B(b)=(2\pi)^{-1}\mathbf 1_{0\lt b\lt2\pi}$, a similar computation yields $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=(2\pi)^{-1}f_A((x^2+y^2)^{1/2})(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}\mathbf 1_{0\lt x^2+y^2\lt1}.$$ This is the uniform distribution on the unit disk if $f_A:a\mapsto2a\mathbf 1_{0\lt a\lt1}$.

To achieve this, one can use the original uniform random variables $A$ and $B$ and consider $$(X,Y)=(\sqrt{A}\cos B,\sqrt{A}\sin B).$$

Comment: There is no guessing here, is there?

Comment: There is no guessing involved in the approach described in my answer, is there?

Comment: If $f_C(a)=2a$ and $f_A(a)=1$ on $(0,1)$, then $P(C\leqslant a)=a^2=P(A\leqslant a^2)=P(\sqrt{A}\leqslant a)$ for every $a$ in $(0,1)$ hence $C$ and $\sqrt{A}$ are identically distributed.

Comment: ((Several comments by the OP are now deleted.))

Comment: Your comment explains the answer - why not to edit it?

Answer (score 1):

Given independence of $A$ and $B$ you have a uniform distribution of $(A,B)$ over the rectangle $[0,1]\times[0,2\pi]$ in cartesian coordinates - random samples should scatter quite evenly over the rectangle.
However transformation into polar coordinates $(A,B)\mapsto (R,\theta)=(A,B)$ contracts the part of rectangle $A\approx 0$ into a tiny region around the disc centre, while the stripe at $A\approx 1$ will get streched into a $2\pi$-long ring along the disc's edge. Random samples of $A,B$ will get concentrated at the center of the disc and dispersed near its edge, thus the resulting distribution will have a maximum at the disc centre and will decrease towards the edge. You have to extend the central region by appropriate modification of $A\to R$ function, so that equal-area parts of the rectangle map onto equal-area parts of a disc.

The area-scaling factor of a function is caclulated as a Jacobian determinant of the mapping function, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_determinant). You need a function which has Jacobian=const.